# How to selectively enable a Dropdown List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form containing two DropDowns lists:

1. Marital Status
2. No. of Children

Now I would like to enable the No. of Children DropDown upon selection of following items in the Marital Status DropDown:

1. Widow
2. Divorced
3. Awaiting Divorce

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

In the MaritalStaus  DropDownList Selected Index changed event, If the selected values match your options then enable the NoOfChild  DropDownList.

```
   protected void MaritalStaus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {
          //Match the selected value here : for Example:
          if (MaritalStaus.SelectedValue.Equals("Divorced") || /*Other Comparisions */)
          {
             NoOfChild.Enabled = true;  
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*DropDown* lists have *ListItem* collection in them. Each *ListItem* has a *Text* and a *Value*. Try setting the text as "Divorced" and value as "D" or better to an integer like "1", something similar to ID. You will get these Text/Value from a Database table if you are retrieving it from the Database.

Make the No. of Children *DropDown* `Enabled = false` by default and then `Enable = true` as explained in the code snippet above by ebad86.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use cascading dropdown from ajaxcontroltoolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaritalStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlMaritalStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Widow" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Divorced" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Awaiting Divorce" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNoOfChildren" runat="server" Enabled="false">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" />
    <!-- and so on -->
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
protected void ddlMaritalStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlMaritalStatus.SelectedItem.Text == "Widow") // if widow is selected
        ddlNoOfChildren.Enabled = true;
    else
        ddlNoOfChildren.Enabled = false;
}
```